# When calling one procedure from another: ERROR: procedure parameter "..." is an output parameter but corresponding argument is not writable

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have the below Postgres stored procedure with an INOUT parameter.

```
PROCEDURE inner_proc(IN pid INT, INOUT pmsg TEXT);
```

I am able to call this procedure successfully from anonymous block.

```
do
$$
declare
v_id int := 4;
v_msg text;
begin
call inner_proc(pid => v_id, pmsg => v_msg);
raise notice '%', v_msg;                                                   
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Above anonymous block prints `'Success'` as expected.
But when I call this procedure inside another procedure, it is failing.

```
PROCEDURE outer_proc()
as
$$
declare
   v_id int := 4;
   v_msg character varying(1000);
begin
call inner_proc(pid => v_id, pmsg => v_msg);
raise notice '%', v_msg;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

When I call the above procedure `outer_proc`, I get the below error.

```
call outer_proc();
```

```
ERROR:  procedure parameter "pmsg" is an output parameter but corresponding argument is not writable
```

Can someone help on how to resolve this?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have found the issue is because the INOUT parameter of inner_proc is of TEXT datatype, whereas I passed a CHARACTER VARYING parameter from outer_proc. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Why not make "inner_proc" a function that returns the status?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this is just a sample procedure I created out of the actual procedure which I was working. I'm not supposed to change it into a function as it impacts many other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that `v_msg` in `outer_proc` is of type `character varying`, but the parameter `pmsg` of `inner_proc` is of type `text`.

So when you call `inner_proc` with `v_msg`, PostgreSQL performs a *type cast*. In the case of `character varying` → `text`, this is just a “type coercion”, because the internal representation of these types is identical, but it could also be a real conversion like `integer` → `bigint`.

Now this works fine for the `IN` direction, but now the argument to `inner_proc` is no longer a plain variable, but an expression that contains a parameter, just as if you had passed `v_msg || 'tail'`.  Of course it is not possible to assign the output value to such an expression, hence the error.

One would feel tempted to argue that the result could simply be cast back to `character varying`, but a) nobody implemented extra processing for that special case, and b) there is no guarantee that there is always a cast in the opposite direction.